# Odd shadows in object mode

Tags: modeling, mesh

When I go to object mode to view my mesh there's strange errors appearing.
[image: the errors]
When I go to edit mode and zoom in, it turns out to be strange overlaps that I can fix by hand. Is there a manual way to fix this or way to prevent it in the future? I used the mirror modifier and subdivision in that order and then sculpted it.

[image: the mesh issue]

Comment: Those look like artifacts from bad topology due to the sculpting origin of the model, hard to tell without seeing your mesh in wireframe. Have you tried removing doubles?

Comment: added the typology to question

Comment: Looking at you model it is definitely from bad topology generated by sculpting. You have small faces or overlapping vertex in those spots, and removing doubles doesn't seem to solve it. Go one by one and manually move those vertex to the faces are not inverted

Comment: Is there a way to prevents this in the future as the errors are not mirrored on each end. Would the decimate modifier fix these issues or worsen them?

Comment: Well this is a problem inherent to sculpting, not really solvable if you use this as a modelling method. Ideally though you should be hand modelling something along these lines https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=im9XZf2C1s0